# Problema al evaluar una variable de sesion, no ejecuta la sentencia if usando php y html en servidor gratuito 0000webhost

Tags: php, html, mysql, lógica

hola el problema es extraño ya que cuando evaluó la variable de session en mi servidor local si ejecuta de forma correcta mi lógica, pero cuando ejecuto el mismo código en el servidor remoto no ejecuta mi sentencia if a que se puede deber, el servidor que utilizo es 000webhost.com, creen que el problema es por que sea gratuito el servidor? mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['cnombre'])){// si la variable existe se manda a otra pagina  pagina
  header('location:../ope/datoscotizacion.php');

?>
<?php }else{


//a qui hay codigo que si, la variable de session: cnombre No  existe se ejecutara, no pongo el codigo de esta parte por que es muy extenso.
}
?>
```

y si ejecuto el mismo codigo en mi servidor local si funciona de maravilla no se a que se deba, creen que el hosting 0000webhost soporta comparación de variables de session, creen que si la ejecuto en uno de paga servirá saludos espero me orienten soy nuevo.

Comment: Hola, ¿Como creas tus variables de sesión?

Comment: asi '$_SESSION['cnombre']=htmlentities($_POST['nombre']);'

Comment: ¿Tienes la función `session_start();` definida al principio del fichero desde el cual quieres acceder a tus variables `$_SESSION`?

Comment: Prueba así: `<?php 
 session_start();
 var_dump($_SESSION);
 if(isset($_SESSION['cnombre'])){ 
  header('Location:../ope/datoscotizacion.php');
 }else{
  echo "Al menos un echo de algo para probar";
 }
?>` O sea, poniendo `session_start();`  como bien ha dicho @Ferni. Luego, respeta la sintaxis (siempre he visto `Location` escrito con `L` mayúscula). Y... no sé por qué abres y cierras bloques de código PHP así.

Comment: gracias lo intentare así como me mencionas, el session_start(); si esta solo que puse solo ese código para que es el que da problemas en el servidor remoto en el local funciona bien